# nature protection vs nature conservation

Tags: word-choice

I have a certificate which is translated into English. 
It says that I am specialised in **Nature Protection**.

> I am wondering.. isn't **Nature Conservation** a better choice to use in a Certificate?

>
Thank you for the answers!

Comment: Yes, Nature Conservation is a better collocation. With "protection" we tend to use "environmental protection".

Answer (score 1):

"Conservation" by itself automatically implies the conservation of *natural resources*.  For example, the state of California in the United States has a department called the [California *Conservation* Corps](https://ccc.ca.gov/what-we-do/), a government-sponsored program that sponsors a year of paid service for young people to work on various environmental projects.

Still, for an official certificate it's better to be reasonably specific, so *Natural Conservation* is on the right track, although I would recommend *Natural Resource Conservation* as the more idiomatic option.

[Edit] *Nature Conservation* works as well.  It's a matter of opinion which of the two is better.

Harvard actually offers a certificate in [Natural Resource Management and Sustainable Ecosystems](https://www.extension.harvard.edu/academics/professional-graduate-certificates/natural-resource-management-sustainable-ecosystems), which is more wordy but also more clearly defines the scope of the certification.

Comment: I think "Nature Conservation" would be better than "Natural Conservation." "Natural Conservation" sounds like conservation that occurs without human intervention.

Comment: @Tashus Harvard offers a certificate in [**Natural** Resource Management and Sustainable Ecosystems](https://www.extension.harvard.edu/academics/professional-graduate-certificates/natural-resource-management-sustainable-ecosystems)  so either seems fine to me.

Comment: There "natural" is part of "natural resource". The degree relates to the management of natural resources, not to the natural management of resources. Likewise "natural resource conservation" would be a good synonym. However, "natural conservation" implies that the conservation itself is natural.

Comment: @Tashus  Sure, we can quibble until the cows come home -- but in the context of a certificate titled "Natural Conservation", awarded to a human being, the intended meaning is obvious.

Comment: The intended meaning may be obvious, but the word choice is odd. It really should be "Nature Conservation" to mean "conservation of nature" with "nature" being a noun adjunct. "Natural Conservation" means "conservation that is natural". I'm happy to make an alternate answer if you don't agree, but I think the rest of your answer is great.

Comment: @Tashus  Eh, I think you're probably right.  I'll edit.

Comment: Maybe it could go either way... I found results for "natural conservation" on the web, but it sounds so odd to me...